Quotient space of $Z_2$ involution of $S_2 \times S_2$
I need to find a $Z_2$ involution of $S^2 \times S^2$ that has the same isometries as $S^2 \times S^2$ and has $S^1 \times S^1$ as fixed points. From https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20836/involutions-of-s2 I learn that this is possible in the case of a single $S^2$, but I am not able to find similar results for $S^2 \times S^2$.
Consider $S^2 \times S2$ with coordinates $(\theta_1, \phi_1, \theta_2, \phi_2)$, $\theta_1, \theta_2 \in [0,2\pi)$, $\phi_1, \phi_2 \in [0,\pi]$. Consider the $Z_2$ involution that acts as,
$(\theta_1, \phi_1, \theta_2, \phi_2) \rightarrow (\theta_1, -\phi_2, \theta_2, -\phi_1)$
The fixed locus is the set of points in the equators: $S^1 \times S^1$.
What is the quotient space?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

I tried to improve it. Is it correct now?

Yes, it is better.
